# Scheduling to start and stop Ec2 instance in aws compaired to azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to start and stop my EC2 instances at a specific time of the day.
There is a scheduled start and stop VMS options available in Azure.

I am wondering if something similar to that is present in AWS.
if not what is the best way to achieve it?
assuming 7am I start my EC2 and stop it by 9pm IST. I am also aware of the cloud watch event integrated with lamnda option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The lambda function would be only required to start your instance, if you want to trigger it using CloudWatch (CW) Event rule. The reason is, that you can stop the instance directly, using CW [built-in targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html):

> Built-in targets: EC2 CreateSnapshot API call, EC2 RebootInstances API call, **EC2 StopInstances API call**, and EC2 TerminateInstances API call.

Sadly, there is no build-in target for starting the instance, thus lambda function is needed for that.

Comment: just curious which CloudWatch event are you planning to use to trigger the EC2 termination? The OP was about scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

Create two different Lambda function to launch and terminate an EC2 instance and [schedule them via CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html). For the Lambda you can use any language from the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/). To select a particular instance to terminate, the EC2 instance can be [tagged](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) to segregate it. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/) is the solution for the same.

Comment: Why would you need two functions?

Comment: @Marcin - One for Launch and the other Terminating the EC2 instance.

Comment: Hi @Marcin hope you're doing well. 
I have the idea of cloud watch event with lambda. We can handle it in one function by checking the current state of the instance. 
But is there any other way. Azure provides an inbuild option for this, is something similar present in AWS?

Comment: [Here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status) is the link for the Boto3 API (Python AWS SDK) to get the status of the EC2 instance. Similar API can be got for other languages also. And one Lambda makes more sense, one less thing to worry about :)

Comment: @sumanthshetty Hi. I'm fine thank you. CloudWatch Event would be the normal way of doing this. But the lambda would be only needed to start the instance. Stopping can be done directly using CW Event rule target.

Comment: @Marcin awesome, 
can i get any reference link to it?

Comment: @sumanthshetty No problem. I added an answer with the reference and extra info.

Comment: @Marcin could you help me out with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589534/cron-job-cloud-watch-event-error-event-pattern-contains-invalid-value-can-onl

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete guide https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/. Let me know if that helps.

As suggested by Praveen Sripati https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/ works pretty well.

Comment: The AWS Knowledge Center solution is a but flawed as the EC2 Instance IDs is hardcoded into it. Before the Lambda is triggered the EC2 Instance IDs have to be modified, which doesn't make much sense for the sake of automation. Tagging the EC2 is one way I can think about narrowing an EC2 instance to be shutdown.