# Cron job cloud watch event error: "Event pattern contains invalid value (can only be a nonempty array or nonempty object)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to set a schedule using a corn job expression for a lambda function target.
The goal is to run the lambda function every day at 7 am IST.

My cron job expression is:

```
0 7 * * * ....
```

have set the target to be a lambda function.

While configuring the event I get the following error:

```
Event pattern contains an invalid value (can only be a nonempty array or nonempty object); All added targets need to be configured correctly
```

for cron job expression I just referred few links online, don't know if I am correct at the expression.

Could someone let me know why this error is popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
0 7 ? * * *
```

All the times are in GMT, thus you would have to adjust the above to match your time zone.

[image]

Comment: Is there any reference for this patter so that I can have study on it?

Comment: @sumanthshetty Not tutorial, but handy website https://crontab.guru/

Comment: just to check i added 55 11 ? * * * as expression, But lambda is not being triggered. 
How can i verify this event?

Comment: @sumanthshetty Check the [lambda permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-lambda-not-triggered/).

Comment: can't find any matrix for this event. 
I am able to test the lambda function which is running as expected

Comment: In the link you shared. It asked to check 'invlocation' and 'faildinvocation' matrix for that event

Comment: @sumanthshetty "Metrics", not "martix". Just try adding the needed permissions as shown there.

Comment: sorry for the typo my bad. 
I have created an event through the console. 
the docs state that the permission will be added automatically.

anything to do with 'target' -> 'configure input'?

Comment: @sumanthshetty Have you confirmed that the permisions are in place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223818/discussion-between-sumanth-shetty-and-marcin).